# Backbone.js. saving JSON data to local storage

Tags: json, cordova, backbone.js

Currently i have this code for my app i'm working on. I have trouble with the backbone i hope you can help me.

**localstorage-adapter.js**

```
app.adapters.employee = (function () {

console.log("Loading localstorage adapter module");

var findById = function (id) {

        var deferred = $.Deferred(),
            employees = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("employees")),
            employee = null,
            l = employees.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (employees[i].id === id) {
                employee = employees[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        deferred.resolve(employee);
        return deferred.promise();
    },

    findByName = function (searchKey) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred(),
            employees = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("employees")),
            results = employees.filter(function (element) {
                var fullName = element.firstName + " " + element.lastName;
                return fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });
        deferred.resolve(results);
        return deferred.promise();
    },

    findByManager = function (managerId) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred(),
            employees = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("employees")),
            results = employees.filter(function (element) {
                return managerId === element.managerId;
            });
        deferred.resolve(results);
        return deferred.promise();
    };


// Store sample data in Local Storage
window.localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(
    [
        {"id": 1, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "King", "managerId": 0, "managerName": "", "reports": 4, "title": "President and CEO", "department": "Corporate", "cellPhone": "617-000-0001", "officePhone": "781-000-0001", "email": "jking@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "james_king.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejking", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 2, "firstName": "Julie", "lastName": "Taylor", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 2, "title": "VP of Marketing", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0002", "officePhone": "781-000-0002", "email": "jtaylor@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "julie_taylor.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejtaylor", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 3, "firstName": "Eugene", "lastName": "Lee", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 0, "title": "CFO", "department": "Accounting", "cellPhone": "617-000-0003", "officePhone": "781-000-0003", "email": "elee@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "eugene_lee.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeelee", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 4, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Williams", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 3, "title": "VP of Engineering", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0004", "officePhone": "781-000-0004", "email": "jwilliams@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "john_williams.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakejwilliams", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 5, "firstName": "Ray", "lastName": "Moore", "managerId": 1, "managerName": "James King", "reports": 2, "title": "VP of Sales", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0005", "officePhone": "781-000-0005", "email": "rmoore@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "ray_moore.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakermoore", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 6, "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "Jones", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "QA Manager", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0006", "officePhone": "781-000-0006", "email": "pjones@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "paul_jones.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakepjones", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 7, "firstName": "Paula", "lastName": "Gates", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "Software Architect", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0007", "officePhone": "781-000-0007", "email": "pgates@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "paula_gates.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakepgates", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 8, "firstName": "Lisa", "lastName": "Wong", "managerId": 2, "managerName": "Julie Taylor", "reports": 0, "title": "Marketing Manager", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0008", "officePhone": "781-000-0008", "email": "lwong@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "lisa_wong.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakelwong", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 9, "firstName": "Gary", "lastName": "Donovan", "managerId": 2, "managerName": "Julie Taylor", "reports": 0, "title": "Marketing Manager", "department": "Marketing", "cellPhone": "617-000-0009", "officePhone": "781-000-0009", "email": "gdonovan@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "gary_donovan.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakegdonovan", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 10, "firstName": "Kathleen", "lastName": "Byrne", "managerId": 5, "managerName": "Ray Moore", "reports": 0, "title": "Sales Representative", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0010", "officePhone": "781-000-0010", "email": "kbyrne@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "kathleen_byrne.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakekbyrne", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 11, "firstName": "Amy", "lastName": "Jones", "managerId": 5, "managerName": "Ray Moore", "reports": 0, "title": "Sales Representative", "department": "Sales", "cellPhone": "617-000-0011", "officePhone": "781-000-0011", "email": "ajones@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "amy_jones.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeajones", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"},
        {"id": 12, "firstName": "Steven", "lastName": "Wells", "managerId": 4, "managerName": "John Williams", "reports": 0, "title": "Software Architect", "department": "Engineering", "cellPhone": "617-000-0012", "officePhone": "781-000-0012", "email": "swells@fakemail.com", "city": "Boston, MA", "pic": "steven_wells.jpg", "twitterId": "@fakeswells", "blog": "http://coenraets.org"}
    ]
));

    // The public API
return {
    findById: findById,
    findByName: findByName,
    findByManager: findByManager
};
```

}());

**EmployeeModel.js**

```
app.models.Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

 app.models.EmployeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.models.Employee,
url: 'http://www.bonar.si/api/restaurants',

initialize: function(){
    console.log("Employees initialize");
},

parse : function(response) {
    console.log("response", response);
    localStorage.setItem('json', JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log("local storage:", localStorage.getItem('json'));
    return response;
```

} 
});

So, i have JSON data in my local storage and then i'm working with this data. But now i want to save JSON data from URL to the local storage just once per day and save it to the local storage.

So idea is to get fresh data once per day and save it to local storage, and then manipulating with this data from the local storage, so i don't need to request JSON from URL for everything i do.

in EmployeeModel.js i get data from url to collection and save it to the localstorage, but now i'm lost. I get easly lost with backbone.

thanks for all the help.

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: now i have json already in local storage, you can see it in localstorage-adapter.js. But i want to get it from url. I started something in EmployeeModel.js, now when i run the app i get the data from url.
But the issue is that i want to get the data from url just once per day and save it local storage. And when i use data in the app i want to load it from local storage.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood right, you need to refresh the employee data once a day? 
One of my apps does this. My approach was to keep a localStorage variable with the refresh timestamp. 
The refresh function is called every time you open the app (from onDeviceReady function). If the refresh timestamp in localStorage is older than a day, or is null, it goes on to fetch the data from the URL, and sets the update date to now.